# one echo command appending 1 message to 2 different lines

Tags: bash

Im trying to echo a line in a for loop ,something like this.

```
echo "IP=$p some message $l" >> /dir/file
```

the problem is that its coming out like this

```
IP=ipadress
some message loutput
```

the p variable is coming from a `for p in ...` and the l variable is equal to a line coming from a tail command
i think its due to the variable substitution in $p , but im not sure.
i want all of it to come out in just one line, what am i doing wrong?

```
for p in $(cat /home/ips)
do
```

Comment: That means that `$p` ends with a newline character. So the problem is with how you're setting that variable.

Comment: Adding to what @Barmar said, please include the exact code setting `p` in the question.

Comment: i have updated the description with the for function that sets p

Comment: Unless the value of `IFS` was modified, there's no way for that loop to create a value of `p` that ends in a newline. (Related, see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the proper way to iterate over the lines of a file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "IP="$p" some message "$l >> /dir/file
```

I suggest this because, for example:

```
temp=$(ls -1)
echo $temp
```

gives:

```
file0 file1
```

But

```
echo "$temp"
```

gives:

```
file0
file1
```

Comment: its outputs the same way as in the description

Comment: Interesting. Ok. The logic behind me answer is that when a bash variable is quoted, the newline chars are included, where as no quotes doesn't. I will add info to my answer. Apologies for that.